# reading columns of a tabdelimited file into variables

Tags: python, csv

Given a tab delimited file in the following format, I need to perform operations  on column-wise manner.  The easiest solution that I know is to use pandas package, however my file being couple of gigs, I am having difficulty reading it. So I decided to use normal streaming method.

Here, I want to generate column variables dynamically (the number of columns are ~ 500), each of which will store all the values in that particular column including blanks. For ex:
variable `a` will be a list `[11,22,31,,42,555]`.

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
11      9   9   1   6
22  8   0   8   2   
31  7       7   3   5
    6   1   6       4
42  6   2   5   2   3
555     3   4   1   2
```

How can I generate these variables by reading the entire file just once?

Comment: if it's a couple gigs, just use pandas, no method is going to be significantly faster without a lot more time put into making it. If you use pandas just index over the columns, and transpose the DataFrame

Comment: It can't load the whole file into memory and seems like loading for ever. I have latest version of pandas.

Comment: I use pandas 0.11 and I just recently loaded 10 dataframes between 1 and 4 gigs each into saved files and itdid take about 30 minutes, but I used pickle to save them on my computer! All I am saying, is that waiting those 30 minutes is worth it because what takes 20 lines in the other methods and still will take a decent amount of time, is really just a built in method in `pandas`

Comment: Meanwhile, why do you want to dynamically create ~500 variables named `a`, `b`, … instead of creating a `dict` (or `list`) with ~500 entries (or just a table/array with one more dimension)?

Comment: @RyanSaxe Thanks a lot for your insight. It is frustrating sometimes when you are not knowing how much more time it is going to take. I will try using pandas again.

Comment: Great! I did provide an answer that is equivalent to what pandas has to offer using numpy, but pandas still is meant for dealing with things like this!

Comment: If you know how many lines there are you can per allocate space and save a huge amount of time- as your columns grow you risk a lot of memory reallocation. You say you can't have the whole file in memory at once - then what makes you think you can have these lists in memory? If you end up using virtual memory for this operation you are toast.

Comment: @Floris: Pre-allocating doesn't usually save much time in Python; it expands pretty zealously, not to mention that the time for 2G loops in Python is so much higher than in C that the cost of, say, 48 reallocate-and-copy calls is swamped. Of course it's always worth profiling to check, but usually it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You've really got two questions in one here.

---

> The easiest solution that I know is to use pandas package, however my file being couple of gigs, I am having difficulty reading it. So I decided to use normal streaming method.

Don't do that. Pandas can handle huge amounts of data with a lot less memory and time than anything you write in pure Python. And less verbosely, as well. It's conceivable that dropping down to `numpy` and then pandasizing the results after reading will help, but dropping down to pure Python is guaranteed to make things worse.

If you have a problem with your code, show us your code (and enough information to generate equivalent sample data).

---

> Here, I want to generate column variables dynamically (the number of columns are ~ 500), each of which will store all the values in that particular column including banks. For ex: variable a will be a list [11,22,31,,42,555].

*Definitely* don't do that. You almost never want to generate variables dynamically like this. There is no benefit to it, and there are plenty of downsides.

This is exactly what dictionaries are for. Instead of this:

```
for column in columns:
    create_variable_named(column[0]).set_to(column[1:])
```

Just do this:

```
column_dict = {column[0]: column[1:] for column in columns}
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
column_dict['a']
```

And, if you want to iterate over all your columns, instead of this:

```
for col in a, b, c, d, …, zz, aaa, …:
```

You can just do this:

```
for col in column_dict.values():
```

---

If you really, really want to create dynamic variables, you can. Depending on what scope or namespace you want to add them to, it's one of the following:

```
globals()[name] = value
locals()[name] = value
setattr(module, name, value)
setattr(obj, name, value)
setattr(cls, name, value)
```

… and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet if you really don't want to use pandas, use numpy because numpy does have a transpose effect so you can change it so the columns are the index!

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open('file_name.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reading = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    columns = reading.next()
    hold_files = []
    for row in reading:
        hold_files.append(row)
    data = np.array(hold_files)
    data = data.T
```

now `data` is an array where each item is an array containing each item that was in each column! Still costly and pandas is still better for all of this, but this does answer your question!

Also, I suggest using `pickle` to save it to disk! It will take more time, but you wont have to iterate through it again! Here is how you would do that:

```
import pickle
def pickleSave(data, pickleFile):
    output = open(pickleFile, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, output)
    output.close()
    print "file has been saved to %s" % (pickleFile)
def pickleLoad(pickleFile):
    pkl_file = open(pickleFile, 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pkl_file.close()
    return data
```

this will save whatever is in `data`, an array, dataframe, etc. to whatever filename you want:`pickleFile`

the following will save the array I just made!

```
file_name = "my_array.txt"
pickleSave(data,file_name)
```

now whenever you want to use that array, you have it saved and can load it with the following:

```
loaded_data = pickleLoad("my_array.txt")
```

now the variable `loaded_data` contains the array I previously created! You can use this on any type of file!

Answer (score 1):

From a comment:

> It can't load the whole file into memory and seems like loading for ever.

If this is your problem, you're attacking it wrong. If you don't have enough memory to hold the whole file at once, you probably don't have enough to hold the whole array at once either. You *definitely* won't if you're using pure-Python objects, but probably not even with `pandas` or `numpy` either.

So, what you need to do is convert it on the fly from one disk-based format to another, and then rewrite your code to process the data off the disk much more quickly than the original file.

One obvious possibility is a file that you can random-access seek or mmap through. For example, let's say you've got 500 columns full of values that all fit within `range(0, 1<<32)`, and you don't know how many rows you have.

Iterate the csv once just to count the rows, then create a file of `4 * 500 * rows` bytes, then iterate the csv again to fill it out using the `struct` module. Then you can access any column by just creating an `mmap` view over `4 * rows * col, 4 * rows * (col+1)`.

Or, alternatively, transpose on the fly. This will be simpler, and have half the I/O, but may be slower (because of both memory and disk cache effects).

If you only need by-column random access, not by-row, just create a file for each column, and to handle any column, just `mmap` the appropriate file, or read it via `struct` or `array`, or just use `pandas` or `numpy` to read/write each one (or possibly just `pickle` a `pandas` table/`numpy` array directly).

Another possibility is to use a key-value database and store big blobs in it, equivalent to the files. (In fact, if you're planning on pickled tables/arrays, a `shelve.shelf` is a key-value database where the values are persisted by pickling.)

To pick from those ideas arbitrarily, here's how you'd create separate files, transpose on the fly, and store the data using `struct`:

Let me give you an example with separate files and `struct`:

```
import csv
import struct

# You may want to check whether the column_foo.dat files already exist and are
# at least as new as input.csv, so you don't re-generate them unless the input
# data changes. That's obviously only a worthwhile optimization if you run the
# script multiple times on the exact same input.

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
    column_names = next(reader)
    column_files = [open('column_{}.dat'.format(column_name), 'wb')
                    for column_name in column_names]
    for row in reader:
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            value = int(col)
            column_files[i].write(struct.pack('!I', value))
    for f in column_files:
        f.close()
```

Now, to access a column later:

```
def get_column(name):
    with open('column_{}.dat'.format(name), 'rb') as f:
        fsize = os.path.getsize(f.fileno())
        length = fsize / 4
        fmt = '!{}I'.format(length)
        return struct.unpack(fmt, f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a dictionary of lists:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    header = infile.readline()
    col_values = {var:[] for var in header.split()}
    var_idx_dict = {idx:var for idx,var in enumerate(header.split())}

    for line in infile:
        values = line.split('\t')

        for idx,value in enumerate(values):
            var = var_idx_dict[idx]
            col_values [var].append(value)
```

`col_values` should contain string keys of your column headers, with each key pointing to a list of all the values in that column.

EDIT: given that your file is very large and I don't know your environment, and you're having trouble with pandas, consider giving PyTables a try. I can provide some assistance with that...it depends on your end goal (basic math? statistics? data formatting?).

Comment: `col_values` will be a *huge* dictionary.

Comment: exactly!! this does answer the question though, but honestly, pandas was made for dealing with stuff like this and even though it would take a bit extra time, it would be worth it

Comment: Yeah, if this takes a 2GB in pandas, it's going to take something like 8GB in a dict. Not to mention how long it'll take to iterate over the whole thing.

Comment: Also, there's no real reason to make this a `dict` of `lists`, since the keys are just the numbers from 0-499, so a `list` would do just as well. But really, it makes no difference; there are 500 lists in the top-level object, so who cares how efficient that part is; it's the tens of millions of sub-elements in each of the lists that will kill you.

Comment: @mdscruggs, thanks a lot. Its working on my example data but I will check tomorrow on my actual data.

Comment: Actually the keys will be the column header strings...this solution doesn't assume I know what the OP actually wants to do with these "variables", but it offers a method for reading in all the data into a series of identifiable lists which is what was asked for (assuming his system and Python version are up to the challenge).

Answer (score 0):

You can read it with the `csv` module and a generator:

```
import csv

def get_column(name):
    with open('filename', 'r') as handle:
        reader = csv.DictReader(handle, delimiter='\t')

        for row in reader:
            yield row[name]
```

But Pandas is probably going to be faster once you start doing something with this data.

Comment: Yeah, he can, but that doesn't solve the hard-ish part of the problem (transposing it). The obvious way to do that (creating a list of lists or dict of lists on the fly) is mdscruggs' answer, and has the same problem (lots of wasted memory, very slow). Or, of course, you can feed it into pandas as an iterator, in which case… what was the point of using `csv` instead of just letting `pandas` do the read more quickly?

Comment: Also… you forgot the dialect parameters (at least `delimiter='\t'`) on your reader.

Comment: @abarnert: Because OP specifies that he doesn't want pandas because that was costly, although not much will end up being significantly better

Comment: If someone says "I don't want to use pandas because it's too slow", offering "Here's something 5x slower" probably isn't the answer he's looking for…

Answer (score -1):

```
def readAsCloumVec(fileName):
    reader = open(fileName,'r')
    text = reader.read()
    lines = text.split('\n')#Split the text into lines
    matrix = []
    for i in range(1,len(lines)):
        if(len(lines[i])>0):#Ignore the last useless line
            line = lines[i].split('\t')#The tag is depend on your file format
            matrix.append(line)
    cloumMatrix = []
    cloums = len(matrix[0])
    row = len(matrix)
    print  matrix    
    for j in range(cloums):#transposition the matrix
        cloum = []
        for i in range(row):            
            cloum.append(matrix[i][j])
        cloumMatrix.append(cloum)
    return cloumMatrix

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print readAsCloumVec('test.txt')
```